# libgdx, several stages in one screen

Tags: android, libgdx, screen, stage

I use two stages in one screen. One - for game actors, another - for control buttons and so on. I use FitViewport for game stage.

What function "resize" should I use? Something like this:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    FitViewport vpC = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    stageC.setViewport(vpC);
    stageC.getViewport().update(width, height, true);

    FitViewport vpG = new FitViewport(MyWorld.WIDTH, MyWorld.HEIGHT);
    stageG.setViewport(vpG);
    stageG.getViewport().update(width, height, true);

}
```

doesn't give correct result.

Actors distorted or buttons don't have right coordinates. That depends on what viewport I place first in func resize - vpC or vpG.

What correct method should I use?

Answer (score 9):

Please read the [Viewports wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) once more. Especially the "Usage" part.

You are not supposed to create new viewports on every resize event. This pretty much destroys the functionality of the viewport. Furthermore the way you are currently using the `FitViewport` for `vpC` (please start to use better variable names), it should behave like a `ScreenViewport`. `FitViewport` has a "virtual resolution" which you define once. Then on resize events, when updating the viewport, it will scale this virtual viewport to fit the screen, while maintaining the aspect ratio. (maybe causing black bars).

The last flag of the `Viewport.update(...)` method should also only be `true` in case of UI. You do not want the camera to be centered in case of a "game" `Stage`.

```
public void show() {
    stageC = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    stageG = new Stage(new FitViewport(MyWorld.WIDTH, MyWorld.HEIGHT));
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stageC.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    stageG.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
}
```

However there is one more problem. Since you are using two different viewport scaling strategies for your stages, you need to "activate" them individually before rendering. This can be avoided by using the same `FitViewport` for both stages (easiest solution, probably what you want anyway).

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    // this will "activate" the viewport
    stageC.getViewport().apply();
    stageC.act();
    stageC.draw();

    // now switch the viewport and activate the other one
    stageG.getViewport().apply();
    stageG.act();
    stageG.draw();
}
```

Comment: @noone I'm trying to do something similar with two stages. The viewport.update() method with no parameters doesn't exist?

Comment: @RussWheeler That's correct. It was renamed to `apply()`.

Comment: I actually manage to get it working by doing an update with the parameters in, but good to know it should be apply instead. Quick side question, but this is fine to only do Viewport stuff in render now, no need for anything in resize?

Comment: @RussWheeler If you use different viewports, you HAVE to do it in render. If you have just a single (type) of Viewport, you should do it in resize, because otherwise it's an overhead you won't need in render.

Comment: @noone ok, thanks for the answer, it's what I'm doing, but always good to know you're doing it right

Comment: Thanks for indicating the need to apply() before draw() in render, I have 3 stages "backdrop w/ FillViewport" a 'centerstage" where action is and a 'frontstage' for UI stuff and was very confused as to why they were all being drawn as if from a shared viewport object...